# Which is the better way to delete an array member?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I'm learning OOP, so I have to interact with arrays, not linked list. I have sorted data. The problem is to delete a member of the array (let's call it `DL`). The 1st method I came up with was overwrite data at `i+1` to `i`starting at `DL`'s index and decrease the amount of reading by 1. Later I found out that I can swap the `DL`with the last member then decrease the counting variable by 1. However, I'll have to sort the data again. So which one is better?

Comment: How big are the arrays?  What kind of data is in them? Can it be memcpy'd? Have you considered trying both and profiling?

Comment: I'm so very tired of this random downvoting of posts that don't seem to need it.  He asked a perfectly valid question, no need to be bullied over it.

Comment: My fault, Trung, I realised (belatedly) it was probably the 'learning' that made you discount linked lists, not something inherent in 'OOP' - have removed my comment.

Comment: When you say array, do you mean a "raw" C-style array, a std::vector or a std::array? Also define "better", better for execution speed, better for readability, best OOP practice, what?

Comment: @joe_04_04 The down votes may not be as random as you think, see [Are questions asking for “The best way” always primarily opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348662/are-questions-asking-for-the-best-way-always-primarily-opinion-based). This question does not specify a "what is best" criteria, so it needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Lundin, its very easy to see when a helpful citizen, such as yourself, directly points to a source that helps the OP improve his/her question, but nothing is more discouraging than being down voted and not knowing why (which is easy to do when you are new.. it still happens to me all the time as well).

Comment: @joe_04_04 Indeed, it always helps if down voters leave comments, especially when the question isn't terrible, which this one isn't. I didn't down vote, but I have close voted as unclear until the things addressed in comments are clarified. Since this is explicitly tagged C++, it isn't obvious what "an array" is, for example, which could be clarified with a brief code example.

Answer (score 3):

If it needs to stay sorted, I'd say it's better to overwrite it by shifting every element after your target back one.  Swapping it with the end element and then resorting would require more work, as a swap requires three actions:

1) Copying element one to a temp variable.
2) Copying element two to element one.
3) Copying the temp element to element two.

And this needs to be repeated multiple times in a sorting algorithm.  And if you're working with an array of objects of a struct or class with multiple private data member each, the workload increases even more.

The overwrite takes fewer moves per iteration:

1) Copy `i + 1` to `i`.

So, Id definitely go with overwriting, by moving all elements back one and decreasing count by one.

At any rate, it's probably just best to time both, with your specific data set, and see which one is faster.  This is really simple to do by counting the milliseconds between start and finish of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

"Better" is a very subjective term and which one is more suitable (for whatever definition you choose) depends a great deal on the sort of data sets you're talking about (size, etc).

But I will mention this, the relative time complexities of array shuffle and most "regular" sorts are respectively `O(n)` and `O(n log n)`.

That means the shuffle is likely to be faster in the vast majority of cases.